# Get updated PHP data in JS

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to refresh a div in my HTML page whenever a button `refresh` is clicked. I'm calling a JS function when the user clicks on the button and the JS function should refresh the value of the div with the data that the PHP got from the mysqli database.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

  $name = "Nikita";

  function getItems($botID){
    $mysqli1 = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "XXXXX", "XXXXX");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
          echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }  
    mysqli_select_db($mysqli1, "price");

      $sql1 = 'SELECT * from XXXXX where name = "' . $name . '"' ;

      $result1 =  mysqli_query($mysqli1, $sql1);

      function resultToArray($result) {
          $rows = array();
          while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
              $rows[] = $row;
          }
          return $rows;
      }

      $rows = resultToArray($result1);

      mysqli_close($mysqli1);

      return $rows;
  }
?>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="test">
    Some information here.
  </div>
  <button onclick="refreshFunc()">Refresh</button>

  <script>
    function refreshFunc(){
      document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = <?php echo getItems()[0]["name"]; ?>;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The problem is that the data that the div should be refreshed to is not changing. When the page is loaded the PHP gets values from the database, puts it into the JS function like this:

```
function refreshFunc(){
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "DataFromPHP";
}
```

How would I update the JS function each time the button is pressed so each time I would get new data?

Comment: getElementsByClassName is an array of elements. innerHTML does not exist on an array object

Comment: Unfortunately you can't just echo php values in your <script> tag. Once the script is loaded on the client, any php variables declared there aren't going to change. You need to look into AJAX: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

Comment: use Ajax. it is exactly why we have it

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate the array of selected elements

```
function refreshFunc(){
    var selected = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
    for(var i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
       var item = selected[i];
       item.innerHTML += "DataFromPHP " + i;
    }
}
```

Or you use an ID property to select a single element

```
<div id="test">
    Some information here.
</div>

function refreshFunc(){
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "DataFromPHP";
}
```

Comment: I imagine this would have been a problem, but that your issue is with the PHP. I'll let someone more familiar with PHP help answer the rest of your question. Regards.